# Unable to get correct top and left position of colorbox for each element displayed

Tags: jquery, positioning, colorbox, onload

I am trying to get the "top" and "left" position of the colorbox for each element as the box moves with each display. The first time it returns the wrong positions and then the positions remain unchanged as expected: I have set the width and height expressly. Here is the code:

```
$('a.gallery').colorbox({ 
            onLoad:function(){ 
               var $left_pos = $('#colorbox').css('left');
           var $top_pos = $('#colorbox').css('left');
       alert('Left pos:' + $left_pos + ' Top pos:' + $top_pos);
    },
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    rel:'group1' 
});
                            ...
```

And yes, it does show a bigger box, the first time, for a fraction of a second and then flashes quickly to the box size I have set. The first set of positions correspond to this quickly transitioned-away colorbox.
Am I taking the positions of the wrong element? 
What else is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using left to get position from top too,

```
 var $top_pos = $('#colorbox').css('top'); //change 'left' to 'top' here.
```

Comment: I got the solution. I was using the wrong callback function. Instead of using onload, if I use onComplete, I get the positions correctly. Or so I think.

Comment: The top/left was a typo issue when I asked the question. Thanks anyway.